# Why Ionic ionRefresher event is undefined when pass in the method parameter?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have this code but I couldn't figure out why it is undefined. I'm trying to access the event members. [Ionic v3 documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/api/components/refresher/Refresher/)

```
////ts file
public refresh(event: IonRefresher): void
////html file
<ion-content>
<ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="refresh($event)">
```

I'm using ionic 4.12.0
NodeJS : v10.16.0
   npm    : 6.9.0
   OS     : Windows Server 2016

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in this [example](https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-4-pull-to-refresh-functionality-in-ionic-4-x-application/). I need to access *target* to call the *complete()* method. But I don't know why there is target which is not a member of eventemitter and IonRefresher.

Answer (score 0):

In Your .html

```
<ion-refresher slot="fixed" (ionRefresh)="doRefresh($event)">
    <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
</ion-refresher>
```

In your .ts

```
doRefresh(refresher) {
    console.log('Begin async operation', refresher);

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Async operation has ended');
      refresher.detail.complete();
    }, 2000);
  }
```